# How to make server ignores sent data from client after client get timeout on getting server response?

Tags: sockets, client-server

I'm using socket with O_NONBLOCK, select, keep alive connection and something like HTTP.

each server connection and client side uses a buffer to get all sent data until complete message be received

How to working:

client send data "A"
client try receive response from server
server receive but don't reply immediately
client gets timeout
server send response "A" (but client don't receive now)

another request:

client send data "B"
server send response "B"
client receive "AB" response instead only "B"

the problem is that client receives previous buffer message

source code bellow:

Server.cpp base class:

```
bool Server::start()
{
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    SOCKET client_socket, max_sock;
    Connection* conn;
    int addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    std::list<Connection*>::iterator it, itr;
    int response;
    fd_set fdset, read_fds;

    max_sock = m_socket;
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(m_socket, &fdset);
    onStart();

    while(true)
    {
        // make a copy of set
        read_fds = fdset;
        // wait for read event
        response = select(max_sock + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(response == -1)
            break;
        // check for new connections
        if(FD_ISSET(m_socket, &read_fds))
        {
            response--;
            // accept connections
            client_socket = accept(m_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);
            if(client_socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                conn = new Connection(*this, client_socket, &client_addr);
                m_connections.push_front(conn);
                // add connection to set for wait for read event
                FD_SET(client_socket, &fdset);
                // allow select new sock from select funcion
                if(max_sock < client_socket)
                    max_sock = client_socket;
            }
        }
        // check for received data from clients
        it = m_connections.begin();
        while(it != m_connections.end() && response > 0)
        {
            conn = *it;
            // verify if connection can be readed
            if(FD_ISSET(conn->getSocket(), &read_fds))
            {
                response--;
                conn->receive();
                if(!conn->isConnected())
                {
                    FD_CLR(conn->getSocket(), &fdset);
                    // remove connection from list
                    itr = it;
                    it++;
                    m_connections.erase(itr);
                    delete conn;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            it++;
        }
    }
    onFinish(response >= 0);
    return response >= 0;
}
```

main.cpp Server implementation:

```
void ClientConnection::onReceive(const void * data, size_t size)
{
    const char *str, *pos = NULL;
    HttpParser* p;

    buffer->write(data, size);
    do
    {
        str = (const char*)buffer->data();
        if(contentOffset == 0)
        {
            pos = strnstr(str, buffer->size(), "\r\n\r\n");
            if(pos != NULL)
            {
                contentOffset = pos - str + 4;
                p = new HttpParser((const char*)buffer->data(), contentOffset);
                contentLength = p->getContentLength(); 
                delete p;
            }
        }
        if(buffer->size() - contentOffset < contentLength || contentOffset == 0)
            return;
        proccessRequest();
        keepDataStartingOf(contentOffset + contentLength);
    }
    while(buffer->size() > 0);
}
```

client side code is a simple recv send  with timeout

any idea how to solve?

Comment: What is the problem? Try to re-phase.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov the problem is that client receives previous response, code added

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to make the client's timeout large enough that the client won't timeout unless the server is actually dead... but I'm sure you've already thought of that.  :)

So assuming that's not a good enough fix, the next thing to try is to have the client send an ID number with each request it sends.  The ID number can be generated with a simple counter (e.g. for the client's first request, it tags the request with 0, for the second it tags it with 1, etc).  The server, when sending its reply, will include that same ID number with the reply.

When the client receives a reply, it compares the ID number in the reply data against the current value of its counter.  If the two numbers are the same, it processes the data.  If not, it ignores the data.  Et voila!

Comment: second thing will be used if no other solution exists, the first option is not a good solution because more than 6 seconds (current wait time) waiting for a response to a game can be very time

Comment: I suppose the other approach would be to figure out why your server is taking so long to respond, and fix it so that it responds quicker...